# WebGL three.js cube camera mapping

Tags: three.js

after following 3 different guides for cube mapping in three.js, I've always encounered same errors in the console:

- " ebGL: INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: drawElements: attachment has a
  0 dimension"
- "ebGL: INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: drawArrays: attachment has a 0
  dimension"
- "[.WebGLRenderingContext]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture
  unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have
  incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'"

Those three errors are repated several time in the console.

Here is a guide and a live example i've tried to emulate:

[Guide 1](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2014/05/12/live-cube-maps-reflections-in-your-three-dot-js-game-with-threex-dot-cubecamera/)

[Live Example](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Reflection.html)

Right now my code is similar to the one in the live example:

```
cubeCameraBottom1 = new THREE.CubeCamera(0.1, 5000, 512 );
scene.add(cubeCameraBottom1);      
var provacylGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(8, 8, 70, 32, 32);
var provacylinderMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {  envMap: cubeCameraBottom1.renderTarget } );
provaCil = new THREE.Mesh( provacylGeometry, provacylinderMaterial );
provaCil.position.set(0,0,-20);
provaCil.castShadow = true;
cubeCameraBottom1.position = provaCil.position;
scene.add(provaCil);
```

and this is the render function:

```
function render()
```

{

```
provaCil.visible = false;
cubeCameraBottom1.updateCubeMap( renderer, scene );
provaCil.visible = true;
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

}

Where am I going wrong? It looks like the cube camera is not computing textures in the right way.
How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the example they used r60. Just maybe that's the Problem, and maybe this can help you:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_lose_context/

Comment: thank you for answering!
I'm using rev 60 too.
About the link, if this is a lost of context issue, i didn't get how to fix it

Comment: couldn't make it work on jsfiddle. Everything is online [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yjqwf89073naewa/AADLAIkH9-O36B2yFrSO13u2a?dl=0)